# POST is not creating a Tax class in Magento2 API

Tags: magento2

Unable to create a new Tax Class using POST call
end point -> http://magentohost/rest/default/V1/taxClasses

While creating a new Tax class using API /V1/taxClasses under taxTaxClassRepositoryV1 from the link http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/

The request which I am sending has a header with Content-Type and Authorization and body as below in JSON format,

{
  "taxClass": {
    "class_id": 6,
    "class_name": "newcustomer",
    "class_type": "CUSTOMER",
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}

The response which I get is

```
{
  "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
  "parameters": {
  "fieldName": "class_id",
  "fieldValue": 6
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can manually specify the class_id when creating a new tax class. The existence of a class_id will make the repositories save method attempt to load an entity with that ID and update it. If you remove the `class_id` field from you're request, I believe it will work.